# VB Program to Calculate an Amount Needed to save to Accumulate Another Amount

Tags: vb.net, basic, accumulator

So I'm trying to make a program that will calculate the amount you need to save each month to accumulate a specific amount, given the term and interest rate. However it is giving the wrong amount and I'm not sure why. For example when given a desired amount to accumulate of 40,000, a term of 20 years, and 6% interest rate it should come out with $86.57 per month but instead it gives some other amount. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearSavings(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles txtFuture.TextChanged, txtTerm.TextChanged, txtRate.TextChanged

    lblSave.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim dblFuture As Double
    Dim dblTerm As Double
    Dim dblRate As Double
    Dim dblSave As Double

    Double.TryParse(txtFuture.Text, dblFuture)
    Double.TryParse(txtTerm.Text, dblTerm)
    Double.TryParse(txtRate.Text, dblRate)

    'Convert to decimal
    If dblRate >= 1 Then
        dblRate = dblRate / 100
    End If

    'calculate the savings per month
    dblSave = -Financial.Pmt(dblRate, dblTerm, 0, dblFuture)
    lblSave.Text = dblSave.ToString("C2")

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: For starters we would need to see: `Financial.Pmt`

Comment: its a function in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  we need to see the input values: they need to be in a specific format or you can get "some other amount"

Comment: @ logixologist I did include financial.pmt, it's under "calculate the savings per month". Unless I did it wrong or I need to declare it or something.

Comment: what values are you feeding it? for instance for the 20 year term and the 6% rate ?

Comment: @ Plutonix Like what do you mean values? Like what I'm inputting in the actual program?

Comment: Yes, of course - what are dblRate, dblTerm, and dblFuture.  it doesnt look like dblRate is correct (from object browser: `Double specifies the interest rate per period. For example, if you get a car loan at an annual percentage rate (APR) of 10 percent and make monthly payments, the rate per period is 0.1/12, or 0.0083.`)  6% would be ((6/100) / 12) for a monthly term

Comment: @ Plutonix  Oh, sorry. I put in 40,000 as dblFuture (which is supposed to be the accumulated amount desired), dblTerm was 20 years and dblrate was simply inputted as 6 (however .06 gives the same result).

Also I'm curious as to what is wrong with dblRate, since it doesn't seem any different, unless it requires something special or is out of position.


EDIT: Oh wait, never mind. I missed some of your comment. I'll test that out real quick.

Comment: @ Plutonix Alrightm I altered the line to 
 `dblSave = -Financial.Pmt((dblRate / 100) / 12, dblTerm, 0, dblFuture)`however it still continues to give wrong answers. 

Unless I'm doing it wrong of course.

Comment: since you desire to know the amount "to save each month" months are the Term, so 20 yrs == 20*12 or 240.  try that along with the rate in the correct format (from Object Browser (F2): `Double specifies the total number of payment periods in the annuity. For example, if you make monthly payments on a four-year car loan, your loan has a total of 4 × 12 (or 48) payment periods.`

Comment: @ Plutonix Okay, so I altered the code to `dblSave = -Financial.Pmt((dblRate / 100) / 12, dblTerm * 12, 0, dblFuture)` and it's still not correct (It displays $165.67 as opposed to $86.57). However I'm way closer than I was so we have to be on to something.

Comment: you still have something wrong with one of the input values. `Me.TextBox1.Text = (0 - Pmt((0.06 / 12), 240, 0, 40000)).ToString` results in 86.5724

Comment: It finally works. Thank you so much.